# Maxmind geoipupdate Not Downloading Databases

Tags: linux, ubuntu, geoip, maxmind

I just installed Maxmind's geoipupdate version 2.3.1 on my Ubuntu machine. When I run the command, it does not attempt to download the latest databases, and instead immediately displays this message:

```
Can't open /usr/local/share/GeoIP/GeoLite2-Country.mmdb.gz
```

The GeoIP directory exists in that location, and it already had some .dat files from other things I was trying with the GeoIP Python library, but the .mmdb.gz file is not present before or after running the command. Here's the configuration file I have in `/usr/local/etc`

```
# Please see http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoipupdate/ for instructions
# on setting up geoipupdate, including information on how to download a
# pre-filled GeoIP.conf file.

# Enter your user ID and license key below. These are available from
# https://www.maxmind.com/en/my_license_key. If you are only using free
# GeoLite databases, you make leave the 0 values.
UserId 999999
LicenseKey 000000000000

# Enter the product IDs of the databases you would like to update.
# Multiple product IDs are separated by spaces.
ProductIds GeoLite2-Country GeoLite2-City GeoLite-Legacy-IPv6-City GeoLite-Legacy-IPv6-Country 506 517 533

# The following are for the GeoLite Legacy databases. To update them,
# uncomment.
# ProductIds 506 517 533 GeoLite-Legacy-IPv6-Country GeoLite-Legacy-IPv6-City

# The remaining settings are OPTIONAL.

# The directory to store the database files. Defaults to /usr/local/share/GeoIP
# DatabaseDirectory /usr/local/share/GeoIP

# The server to use. Defaults to "updates.maxmind.com".
# Host updates.maxmind.com

# The desired protocol either "https" (default) or "http".
# Protocol https

# The proxy host name or IP address. You may optionally specify a
# port number, e.g., 127.0.0.1:8888. If no port number is specified, 1080
# will be used.
# Proxy 127.0.0.1:8888

# The user name and password to use with your proxy server.
# ProxyUserPassword username:password

# Whether to skip host name verification on HTTPS connections.
# Defaults to "0".
# SkipHostnameVerification 0

# Whether to skip peer verification on HTTPS connections.
# Defaults to "0".
# SkipPeerVerification 0
```

Is it possible I missed a step when installing geoipupdate? How can I get the command to check for and download an updated database?

Comment: Does the user you are running `geoipupdate` as have permission to write to that directory?

Comment: It appears not, since I ran it with sudo just now and it worked. No messages showed up, but I see that the databases were downloaded to `/usr/local/share/GeoIP`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should run the command in verbose mode:
`geoipupdate -v`

This way you'll understand why the file isn't updated (most probably a faulty `DatabaseDirectory`, or perhaps a wrong `ProductIDs` or `EditionIDs` which will prevent other downloads to complete).